# How to print array value from object in one line?

Tags: php, arrays, object

If I have for example the following class:

```
class Test {
    private $field = array();

    function __construct($field) {
        $this->field = $field;
    }

    public function setField($field) {
        $this->field = $field;
    }
    public function getField() {
        return $this->field;
    }
}
```

And I create an instance of this class:

```
$simpleArray = (1, 2, 3, 4);
$simpleTest = new Test($simpleArray);
```

How can I then print the value of simpleArray[2] in one line? I know this solution:

```
$saveArray = $simpleTest->getField();
echo $saveArray[2];
```

I want to know how to directly access array value after getField(), so that I don't have to save the array to variable:

```
echo $simpleTest->getField()->....?
```

Comment: Is `echo $simpleTest[2];` supposed to be `echo $saveArray[2];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a parameter which could serve as an index for what item to return, as can be seen below.  Adding another method named something like `fieldAt($index)` could be another solution.

```
public function getField($index = null) {
    if($index != null)
    {
        return $this->field[$index];
    }
    return $this->field;
}
```

```
$saveArray = $simpleTest->getField(2); // get the 3rd element in the array
```

Another solution could be to implement the `ArrayAccess` interface, which would allow you to use the array access operators (`[]`) on your object:

```
class Test implements ArrayAccess{
    private $field = array();

    function __construct($field) {
        $this->field = $field;
    }

    public function setField($field) {
        $this->field = $field;
    }
    public function getField() {
        return $this->field;
    }

    public offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->field[$offset]);
    }
    public offsetGet($offset)
    {
        if($this->offsetExists($offset))
        {
            return $this->field[$offset];
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void offsetSet($offset, $value) { } // Can implement this method, if desired
    public void offsetUnset($offset ) { } // Can implement this method, if desired
}
```

```
$testObj[2]; // get the 3rd element in the array
```

Comment: Yeah this solution is fine, but still there must be a way to access it directly from returned array, or is not?

Comment: @JernejJerin:  Not in PHP versions lower than 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

Before PHP 5.4 you can't use dereference and so you can't use `$this->$simpleTest->getField()[position]`. So, for the moment, you can create a method like this:

```
public function getElement($index) {
   if ($index >= 0  &&  $index < count($this->field))
      return $this->field[$index];
   else
      return null;
}
```

and then you can call

```
echo $simpleTest->getElement(position);
```

where position is an integer.

Comment: So in PHP 5.4, I coud wrote it like this: echo $simpleTest->getField[2]?

Comment: @JernejJerin If you meant echo $simpleTest->getField()[2] , yes you will.

Comment: I actually tried it before I created this thread, but it didn't work (still running 5.3.0). Nice to know, that you can do that in 5.4